# Internal Linux machine with Apache that I can access by IP address but not computer name

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system

I have an Ubuntu machine running LAMP. While on the machine I can type localhost or the computers name to access htdocs. From another machine I can only access the machine via its IP Address.

This just started happening recently when someone rearranged the network cables and removed a hub sitting between the machine and the network, which makes me think it wasn't all the stable to begin with anyways.

Any suggestions on where I should start looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the DNS name isn't working I would start with troubleshooting DNS.

Answer (score 1):

You have a DNS problem.

1. Find the DNS server on your network.
2. Add an "A" record specifying the IP address and hostname.

If you have no DNS server, you can add the hostname and IP address to the "hosts" file on the other machine.

Comment: Miles Erickson is right.
First, try to update your DNS server if you have one or just add an entry in your /etc/hosts
IP_address_of_the_web_server Web_server_hostname Save your file and try to ping the webserver by its hostname.
thanks